# mongodb not finding file

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a spring-boot app acting as image server. It receives a image such as:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "images/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity addPortrait(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @PathVariable Long patientId) throws Exception {

        try {
            GridFSFile storedFile = mongoFileService.add( file, id );
            LOGGER.info( "Returning Filename " + storedFile.getFilename() );
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                    .body(  SERVER_URL+ storedFile.getFilename() );

        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error("Error storing file " + file.getOriginalFilename(), ex );
            return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR )
                    .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(MISSING_IMAGE_PATH );

        }
    }
```

which then calls:

```
private GridFsOperations gridFsOperations;

public GridFSFile add(MultipartFile file, Long patientId) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(System.currentTimeMillis());
    sb.append("_");
    sb.append(file.getOriginalFilename());
    return gridFsOperations.store( file.getInputStream(), sb.toString() );
    // return gridFsAppStore.store(file, sb.toString());
}
```

The result returned is correct, and I can see the file in MongoDB with:

```
db.getCollection('fs.files').find({}):
```

[image]

So I am pretty sure the PUT call works.

However, when I try to retrieve that image with the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "images/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getSizedImage(@PathVariable String filename, @RequestParam int width, @RequestParam int height) throws Exception {
        if (savedFile != null) {
            try {
               BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( savedFile.getInputStream() );
               image = resize( image, Method.SPEED, width, height, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS );

               LOGGER.info( "Returning Filename " + savedFile.getFilename() + " sized to " + width + " X " + height );
               return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength( savedFile.getLength() )
                    .contentType( MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG ).body( image );
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error("Error sizing file " + filename + ": " + ex.getMessage());
              return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR )
                    .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body("Error sizing file " + filename + ": " + ex.getMessage() );
           }
       } else {
        LOGGER.error("Could not find requested file " + filename );
        return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND )
                        .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(MISSING_IMAGE_PATH );
    }
    }
```

The MongoFileService to get the image is:

```
@Component
public class MongoFileService {

     @Autowired
     private GridFsOperations gridFsOperations;

      public GridFSDBFile getStore(String filename) throws IOException {

           Query query = new Query( GridFsCriteria.whereFilename().is( filename ) );
    return gridFsOperations.findOne( query );
      }

      public GridFSFile add(MultipartFile file, Long id) throws IOException {

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append(System.currentTimeMillis());
          sb.append("_");
          sb.append(file.getOriginalFilename());
          return gridFsOperations.store( file.getInputStream(), sb.toString() );
      }
```

}

I get nothing.  No error, no image or anything in the log other than:

```
"Error retrieving file " and the file name parameter provided
```

I am using Spring-Boot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, MongoDB 2.4.14, Spring-Data.

Can anyone see why this result is not being returned?

***Updated to show MongoFileService***
I set a breakpoint in the the controller and the file name that is received is "1440128243370_IMG_3415" which is missing the "JPG" extension.  If I manually change the value in the debugger, the file is returned.

To fix this, I added the following to my project:

```
@Configuration
public class AllResources extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just by looking at you code I'd say that the `GridFSDBFile savedFile = mongoFileService.getStore( filename );` is returning `null`. Can you share the code of the `mongoFileService`? One note: I'd personally not use the same log level and error message for the case of `null` and exception. I'd go for warn and `LOGGER.warn("{} could not be found", filename)` and `LOGGER.error("Exception while retrieving file " + filename, ex)` for the exception. I'd personally also prefer to return 404 and 500 in these cases rather than a JSON string but this is up to your design.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the mongoFileService.  That is good advice on the return codes, I will change those as well to just return the code and not the same default message.

Comment: Perfect. I think you have an issue with your query cause `findOne` will return `null` if the `Query` does not match any entry.

Comment: And I think it is really related that you are using a plain `Criteria`. Can you try a `GridFsCriteria.whereFilename().is(filename)`?

Comment: I replaced it (see updated question) and it is still not found.  Is there anyway to turn up the debugging in either Mongo or Spring to see if any errors occur, or is this simply that Mongo can't find it

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to change the URI template variable matching in the `@RequestMapping` for the method in question. The syntax is `{varName:regex}`. To make your `{filename}` variable match everything (including the dot and the file extension), use the following definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "images/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

More details can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex).